# How many sets can a 2-dimensional Venn diagram represent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've seen one, two, three and even four in my daily life. Looking into this I saw one for five, and a less convincing one for six. Is there a limit to how many sets you can represent with closed regions in 2 (or more) dimensions?

Rules:
You may only have one closed region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ $\mathbb{R}^2$ $\left(\text{or }\mathbb{R}^N\right)$ representing membership of each set.
You may only have one closed region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ $\left(\text{or }\mathbb{R}^N\right)$ representing membership of each of the intersections of the sets (equivalently, your plane is split up into only $2^n$ $\left(\text{or }N^n\right)$ regions where $n$ is the number of sets. You may not have two or more disconnected regions which represent the same intersection.

Extentions:
What if we extend into more than two dimensions? If $N$ is the dimension of our space, how many sets can we represent as a function of $N$? Is it exponential, or is there a factorial somewhere?
What do resrtictions on the shapes of the regions do? If we say that the regions can only be circles, we get N+1 as the solution (if that's right). What about elipses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it for any $n$.  The image below shows a Venn diagram for $6$ sets, but it is easy to see how each additional set is added simply by drawing a loop that follows the same path as the loop for the previous set, but makes sure to cross it twice, thus resulting in exactly twice as many regions, each of which represents a different combination. Since you can just keep doing this, you can make a 2-dimensional Venn diagram for $n$ sets for any $n$.

[image]

Another method you can use is to have each successive loop follow the same path as the previous loop but to have it cross the previous loop each time it crosses into a different region. Sorry I don’t have a nice illustration for that.